# Downloading OSM data for large area

Tags: database, geospatial, openstreetmap

I am trying to extract a road network of the entire Melbourne city from open street maps. The bounding box of the city is roughly min_lon: 144.27, min_lat: -38.57, max_lon: 145.60, max_lat: -37.56. However, since this area is quite large, most of the API can not handle this query (e.g., I tried downloading from https://www.openstreetmap.org, and overpass API inside QGIS, unfortunately, none of them work).

Basically, I only need the road types and coordinates for all the highways in Melbourne city. Any idea of how to extract such a graph using OSM or other resources?

Comment: What is unclear about: "Please zoom in or select a smaller area, or use one of the sources listed below for bulk data downloads." ? BTW the [map](https://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=10/-38.0667/144.9350) is indeed big (1.508.818.442 bytes), and is currently downloading here from Overpass API.

Comment: The file can be downloaded here: WeTransfer: we.tl/t-CtWzeuuX9y (within 7 days from now) 

Comment: @Luuk thanks Luuk, but if you open the map file you shared, in the last row, it still shows errors ("<remark> runtime error: Query timed out in "print" at line 1 after 203 seconds. </remark>"). Seems like only part of the map is downloaded.

Comment: I was expecting an error, so I did not look at the file itself, which I probably should have done. Second option is to split, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSM API is not designed for bulk downloads. The API's main purpose is for editing the map.

You can download a larger area by either downloading the full [planet](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) or via [country or area extract](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). Afterwards you can split the file into even smaller regions, for example by using [osmium-extract](https://docs.osmcode.org/osmium/latest/osmium-extract.html) from [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/).

Answer (score 0):

OpenstreetMap states:

> This area is too large to be exported as OpenStreetMap XML Data.
> Please zoom in or select a smaller area,  or use one of the sources
> listed below for bulk data downloads.

If you split your area into 4 parts i did not get errors because of timeouts, using overpass API.

```
map1:  <bounds minlat="-39.0800000" minlon="143.6833000" maxlat="-37.9193000" maxlon="145.3175000"/>
map2:  <bounds minlat="-38.0000000" minlon="143.6833000" maxlat="-37.0000000" maxlon="145.3175000"/>
map3:  <bounds minlat="-39.0000000" minlon="145.0000000" maxlat="-38.0000000" maxlon="146.0000000"/>
map4:  <bounds minlat="-38.0000000" minlon="145.0000000" maxlat="-37.0000000" maxlon="146.0000000"/>
```

NOTE: I did not test if you should have a (small) overlap between the area's. (and also not how smal that overlap should be to finally have all the data)